# Advice to live a good life

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, how-to

Shalom everyone,

In our daily life we face many circumstances, good and bad, and we react likewise.

My thought is to accept everything, certainly the reality. If we can accept everything in our life, we can easily go through our problems and difficulties.

What do the commentaries say about attaining a "good life"?

Comment: Hi @Gembali you might want to rephrase the question as at the moment it suggesting people provide their personal opinions which will mean it will get closed down.

Comment: Honour your parents.

Comment: @Gembali I have edited the question making it more within the allowable parameters of the site. Feel free to revert if you feel it does not ask your question well enough.

Comment: I am also worried that this question is opinion based but with your edit, I think you are asking about basic emuna?

Comment: @RabbiKaii - I tried to remain true to the main thrust of the question which is about attaining a "good life"...

Comment: @Dov I will read your answer later and I'm sure it will be excellent :) In the meantime Gembali, may I recommend [Garden of Emuna](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/2927929), and the section "Gate of Trust" in Duties of the Heart. The latter is available for free online [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Duties_of_the_Heart%2C_Fourth_Treatise_on_Trust.1?ven=Duties_of_the_Heart,_trans._by_Rabbi_Moses_Hyamson,_New_York,_1925&lang=he&with=Navigation&lang2=en)

Answer (score 0):

Rambam expresses this idea very clearly in his [Mishneh Torah, Hilchos Teshuva 9:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Repentance.9.1?ven=Mishneh_Torah,_trans._by_Eliyahu_Touger._Jerusalem,_Moznaim_Pub._c1986-c2007&lang=bi).

He notes that if one observes the Torah, he gains his reward in the next world. If, however, he does it with a sense of joy and happiness, then he receives a good life in this world too.

> When we fulfill all the mitzvot in the Torah, we will acquire all the benefits of this world...
>
> ...God gave us this Torah which is a tree of life. Whoever fulfills what is written within it and comprehends it with complete and proper knowledge will merit the life of the world to come. A person merits [a portion of the world to come] according to the magnitude of his deeds and the extent of his knowledge.
>
> [In addition,] we are promised by the Torah that **if we fulfill it with joy and good spirit and meditate on its wisdom at all times, [God] will remove all the' obstacles which prevent us from fulfilling it**, for example, sickness, war, famine, and the like.
>
> Similarly, He will grant us all the good which will reinforce our performance of the Torah, such as plenty, peace, an abundance of silver and gold in order that we not be involved throughout all our days in matters required by the body, but rather, will sit unburdened and [thus, have the opportunity to] study wisdom and perform mitzvot in order that we will merit the life of the world to come...
>
> **...Thus, you will merit two worlds, a good life in this world, which, in turn, will bring you to the life of the world to come.**